# WooCommerce show decimals in totals

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

Learning PHP and a little stuck on a fairly straight forward issue.
I am trying to edit my WooCommerce invoice

This code `<?php echo $sign.number_format($order->get_subtotal(),2); ?>` Returns $50.98

This code `$first_number = $order->get_subtotal();` Returns a variable of 51, it rounds up as the `,2` is missing.
How do  I add `(),2;` to the above code so it returns that variable just as a number with decimals so i can make calculations with it.

If I try this`$first_number = ($order->get_subtotal(),2);` It breaks as I obviously don't know the correct syntax.

Thanks for any pointers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
$first_number = number_format( $order->get_subtotal(), 2 );
```

number_format() is the php function that is setting the decimals in your first bit of code above.

See http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php

Answer (score 0):

Using Jason's answer this is what I came up with that works. If you need a subtotal minus the orders discount this should work.

```
$orderSubtotal = $order->get_subtotal();
$discountsTotal = $order->get_total_discount();
echo $sign.number_format( ($orderSubtotal - $discountsTotal), 2);
```